# Variables not updating in index.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, count, increment

I'm learning javascript from a course in Udemy (Angela Yu's Web Development Bootcamp).

In the exercise, the variable (count) gets pushed to the array (output). When the function fizzBuzz is run, the variable (count) gets incremented and then added to the array (output).

I was testing my code and figured out that when I run the function the value doesn't get pushed to the array and count resets to 1 each time. My code is below.

Did I accidentally change a setting, we are using the Chrome Developer Tools, under snippets ? What am I doing wrong ?

My code:

```
var output = [];
var count = 1;

function fizzBuzz() {
    
    output.push(count);
    count++;

    console.log(output);
}

fizzBuzz();
```

Comment: How, exactly, are you running this code?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to make it appropriate for Stackoverflow, or it may be closed. Please post code, not images of code. It's not clear what you're asking now. What does "the value doesn't get pushed to the array" mean? Please include what you expect to happen and be as specific as possible about what you're seeing instead.

Comment: @JohnGordon I'm sorry. I can't screenshot it, it turns black when I do, so I tried to take a picture. To write and run the code, the instructor asked us to use the Google Chrome Developer Tools\Snippets.

Comment: @AndyRay Ok, I was trying to post a screenshot of the answer provided by the instructor. When she runs the fizzBuzz function it works for her. I tried to copy her code word for word, including syntax, and it does not work for me. What I mean by "push" is that the value of the variable (count) doesn't get added to the array (output).  I believe that is what the line output.push(count);  is supposed to do.

Comment: @JohnGordon to be more specific, to write and run the code I open a new tab in Chrome, I click on the three vertical dots on the top right hand corner then I navigate to More Tools\Developer Tools. Then there is a small window with the options Page Filesystem Overrides Content Scripts Snippets. We were told to select the Snippets and write our code there.

Comment: Please edit your question to add detail and remove images. Avoid adding excessive detail in comments. Please re-read my comment and read all of "how to ask," don't skip it! Edit your question to include the output you're getting when you run the code, and how that differs from what you expect. The screenshot provided does not show any output from the script, so it's still not clear what you're comparing to.

Comment: Since you are using global variables that code should work fine. I am not sure how you are running this, but as a tip to debug what is actually going on you can use the `debugger` keyword and check what is going on. Put the debugger inside your fizzBuzz method, and run it again, that might give you more insights.

With this you can see what is actually going on with those global variables and even change its values in the console.

Answer (score -2):

The variable `count` is being pushed into the array `output` before `count` is incremented.
If you want `output` to contain `[2]`, then place `count++` on the line above `output.push(count)`.

Also, you may need to call the function: `fizzBuzz();`

Comment: Hi Jacob, thank you for your help. I place the count++ above the output.push(count). And added the fizzBuzz(); to the end of my code. In the video, she calls the function in the console window. The console log for the array (output) now says it is,  [NaN, NaN] Why would it tell me that it is Not a Number ?